# Zend strange behavior: can not process 2nd request when 1st request still running

Tags: php, zend-framework, pdo

I'm building a chat function using Zend Framework.
In javascript, I use ajax to request to `http://mydomain.com/chat/pull` with function pullAction like this

```
public function pullAction() {

        while ( true ) {
            try {
                $chat = Eezy_Chat::getNewMessage();
                if($chat){
                    $chat->printMessage();
                    break;
                }
                sleep ( 1 ); // sleep 1 secound between each loop
            } catch ( Zend_Db_Adapter_Exception $ex ) {
                if ($ex->getCode () == 2006) { // reconnect db if timeout
                    $dbAdapter = Zend_Db_Table::getDefaultAdapter ();
                    $dbAdapter->closeConnection ();
                    $dbAdapter->getConnection ();
                }
            }
    }
}
```

This action will running until other user send some message.
But while this request is running, I can not go to any other page on my site. All of them wait for `http://mydomain.com/chat/pull` to finished it execution.

I searching for a solution all over Google but still not found.
Thank for your help.

Comment: When you say "all of them wait" do you mean "each and every user" or do you mean "all request by the same user hang"? The latter is likely a file locking issue, for instance from Sessions.

Comment: @Gordon I mean "all request by the same user hang"

Comment: In case you are using Sessions, can you try to `Zend_Session::writeclose` the Session *immediately* after you loaded the data you need for it for the request? Does that fix the error?

Comment: let me add that as an answer for you to accept then

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This sounds like Session locking.

When you use Sessions stored on the file system, PHP will lock the session file on each request and only give it free when that request is through. While the file is locked, any other requests wanting to access that file will hang and wait.

Since your chat script will loop forever, checking for new messages, the session file will be locked forever, too, preventing the same user from accessing different sections of the site requiring session access as well.

A solution is to load all the Session Data required to fulfill a Request into memory and then use `Zend_Session::writeClose` as soon as possible to release the lock.